# NoneType object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, audio, pygame, mixer

```
import pygame as pg, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import os

pg.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096) 
pg.init()

a = pg.mixer.music.load("./Sounds/ChessDrop2.wav")
a.play()
```

The code above is what I have written to test whether sound can be played through pygame. My 'ChessDrop2.wav' file is a 16 bit wav-PCM file because when the file was 32 bit PCM, pygame recognised it as an unknown format. Now that error is gone when I run the code but the error below pops up on my shell instead. I have assigned the sound file to the variable 'a' so shouldn't the sound play? My version of python is 3.6.1 and pygame is 1.9.3.

```
a.play()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
```

Comment: errors means that `load()` returns `None` and finally you try to do `None.play()`. Did you check documentation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this functions doesn't return any object to be used, check the documentation:

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load

after loading the file you should use

```
pg.mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CaMMelo stated `pygame.mixer.music.load(filename)` method doesn't return an object.

However, if you are looking for an return object after the load, you may want to try [pygame.mixer.Sound](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) .

> pygame.mixer.Sound
>   Create a new Sound object from a file or buffer object

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
sound = mixer.Sound("yourWaveFile.wav")
sound.play()
```